# what 0 means in pure virtual function

Tags: c++, constructor, pure-virtual

Program below doesn't compile for obvious reasons:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
 public:
  A() { pVirt(); }
  virtual void pVirt() const = 0 { count<<"A::pVirt()"; }
};

int main() {
 A aObj;
 aObj.pVirt();
 reutrn 0;
}
```

Questions:
1. 0 in signature "virtual void pVirt() const = 0" means what?, Is this indicates NULL memory offset in vtable or just a syntax constraint?

1. If 0 is NULL memory offset (if in case it is so) then why VC++ doesn't allow to specify another memory address, and is this the reason why we can't call pure virtual function from outside constructor (MAY BE because vtable is created after an object is fully constructed.)?

Answer (score 5):

> 0 in signature "virtual void pVirt() const = 0" means what?,

The part `=0` is called *pure-specifier*. It makes the virtual function *pure*, and the class *abstract*.

A pure virtual function need not to have definition. You may *optionally* provide a definition outside the class, and a non-abstract derived class *still* has to *override* the function.

```
class A
{
 public:
     virtual ~A() {};
     virtual void f() =0;
};

void A::f() { std::cout << "A::f" << std::endl; } //optional
```

The definition of `f` doesn't make the class non-abstract, so you cannot create instance of `A`:

```
A a; //error - A is abstract
```

Moreover, the derive class has to override `A::f` in order to be non-abstract:

```
class B : public A {};

B b; //error : B is still an abstract class as it didn't override A::f
```

And

```
class C : public A { void f() {} };

C c; //okay : C override A::f
```

And derived class implementation may choose to call the base class implementation:

```
class D : public A { void f() {  A::f(); } }; //defaults to A::f

D d; //okay : D override A::f, but calls A::f internally
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: your answer is a very complete explanation, that clears up what's with the optional declaration of a pure virtual function. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It’s just syntax to denote that the function is pure virtual. It has no actual meaning whatsoever. The C++ designers could just as well chosen to use `pure` or `abstract` in place of `= 0`. I suspect the only reason for not doing so was that they didn’t want to introduce a new reserved word into the language (since that breaks any existing code which already uses the newly reserved word as an identifier).

(It’s not necessary to make such a word reserved since it would be a context sensitive keyword, but the concept of context sensitive keywords has only recently entered mainstream usage, and this syntax is much older.)

Comment: then what is here to stop us from calling it as a non-pure virtual function.?

Comment: @ajay How is that related to your question? The presence of `= 0` is stopping you: C++ simply specifies that any class which has pure virtual functions cannot be instantiated.

Comment: You forgot the most important possibility! `= 42;`

Answer (score 2):

The `= 0` in the function declaration is just syntax: the two
token sequence means that the function is pure, that's all.  And
you cannot replace either of the tokens with anything else: `=
0L` isn't legal, for example.

And the reason you're getting the error is simply because the
syntax isn't allowed.  For historical reasons, if nothing else.
If you want to provide a definition for a pure virtual function,
you must do it outside of the class.

And *if* you provide a definition for a pure virtual function,
you can call it from the constructor; you just have to
disactivate the virtual call mechanism; e.g. `A::pVirt()`.  If
the actual function call involves dynamic resolution, and the
resolution results in a pure virtual function, it is undefined
behavior, regardless of whether the function is defined or not.
The motivation here is to allow you not to define it; normally,
a virtual function must be defined, whether you call it or not,
because the compiler must put its address in the `vtable`, and
if it isn't defined, there is no address.  Making the function
pure virtual tells the compiler that it shouldn't put its
address in the `vtable`.  So you don't have to define it.  But
you may get surprises if you try to call the function through
the vtable.

Comment: +1 nice answer. Just reread Scott Meyers's old [column](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html) on the intricacies of calling virtual functions in constructors: you were correct to point out the error in my now deleted answer (didn't provide added value to your answer).

Answer (score 1):

The `= 0` after a virtual function means that "this is pure virtual function, it must be implemented in the derived function". As in your example, it's still possible to implement the function. It has no other meaning as such - and you can't use other numbers, addresses or anything else. You can have several functions with `=0`, and it will still be the same meaning.